# Meteor import directory test files not eagerly loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, testing, meteor

```
Meteor version 1.7.0.5
Using meteortesting:mocha
```

I have a very simple meteor react app. I added a test file in `imports/startup/simple-schema.tests.js`

```
describe('Todos_item', function () {
  console.log('Todo');
});
```

I was running `npm run test-app` so it should be logged in console but that file actually doesn't run. But when I added this snippet to my `tests/main.js` `Todo` is logged in console. So am I missing something.

My directory tree

[image]

package.json

```
{
  "name": "meteor-bootstrap",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run",
    "test": "meteor test --once --driver-package meteortesting:mocha",
    "test-app": "TEST_WATCH=1 meteor test --full-app --driver-package meteortesting:mocha",
    "visualize": "meteor --production --extra-packages bundle-visualizer"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "7.0.0-beta.55",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.4.1",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "simpl-schema": "^1.5.3"
  },
  "meteor": {
    "mainModule": {
      "client": "client/main.js",
      "server": "server/main.js"
    },
    "testModule": "tests/main.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.11.4"
  }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it `--full-app` thats causing the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New Meteor apps since 1.7 have eager loading turned off by default (which is causing your problem)

The behaviour is controlled by the `meteor` section in your `package.json`.

To restore the eager loading behaviour for tests, delete the `testModule` key-value pair from your `package.json`. It should look like this:

```
  "meteor": {
    "mainModule": {
      "client": "client/main.js",
      "server": "server/main.js"
    }
  },
```

If you want to restore pre-1.7 behaviour for all files, just delete the whole `meteor` section from `package.json`

---

If you don't want to use eager loading, you will need to import all of your test files from the `tests/main.js` file

Comment: Yes I figured out early today but thanks for your answer.

Comment: I am on meteor 1.10 and i want meteor to load all code (import directory) what do i have to do? My package.json has no meteor property

Comment: Ho @Gobliins, the import directory is never eager. Move your code outside `imports` if you want them to load automatically. See: https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html

Answer (score 0):

Also one thing to add when with @Fred answer importing test files have to `use require not import` though I am not sure is it due to my node version or not I am using my node version `v6.11.1`

Comment: Good point. It depends on your test runner. Some will pre-parse your code to handle ES modules, most wont. You can require `@std/esm` to enable import syntax, or put your tests in `.mjs` files for Node to interpret as ES modules. Though that requires a newer node version than 6